# How do you invite friends in Minecraft Classic?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing the new Minecraft Classic in a browser and I've been wanting to play with my friends. Whenever we go to the invite link it doesn't load. Is there a way to play with friends?

Comment: Wow, I just went to the bug tracker to search for the issue and it was the first entry in the list already, because someone had just reported it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We’ve temporarily disabled multiplayer for Minecraft Classic while we work on some performance issues. You can still play it as single player! - AP

Source: https://twitter.com/MojangStatus/status/1126070107279695873